# Ruby on Rails: Custom Actions (Follow up)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, custom-routes

This question is a follow up to this previous question: [Ruby on Rails: Custom actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364858/ruby-on-rails-custom-actions)

As a follow up, what would be the syntax to use a custom action in a form_for? For my app, I have a partial called _invite_form.html.erb, and set the form to have a :url specification that I thought would link the form to the invite action on the Users controller:

```
 <div id = "invite_form">
<h1>Invite</h1> 
<%= form_for(invited, :url => invite_user_path) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "inputform round", :placeholder => "email" %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Invite", :class => "submit_button round" %>
    </div>  
<% end %>
 </div>
```

This partial is called on certain pages, and this error is given:

```
  "No route matches {:action=>"invite", :controller=>"users"}"
```

In my routes.rb file I have included the appropriate lines:

```
 resources :users do
     member do
      get :invite
      post :invite
    end
 end
```

Why is it that the route doesn't work? How do I change these files to make the form use the action "Invite" on the Users controller?

** Forgot to mention earlier: I defined invited in the Users helper: users_helper.rb:

```
 module UsersHelper
   def invited
     @invited = User.new(params[:user])
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you don't have a persistent User just yet, make this a collection operation by:

1. Changing `invite_user_path` to `invite_users_path` in your controller
2. Changing `member do` to `collection do` in your routes

Answer (score 1):

`invite_user_path` expects a user as an argument.  Try `invite_user_path(invited)`.  You will also need to `save` the user before you can compute a path to it.

To experiment, go into `rails console` and see the difference between the following:

```
app.invite_user_path
app.invite_user_path(User.first)
app.invite_user_path(User.new)
```

Comment: I suspect that's because the invited user is still new, and therefore has not been assigned an `id`, and therefore doesn't (yet) have an assigned URL.

Comment: yes, i agree - but that's the thing.. i have other forms that link to a user create action, and these link through fine, and handle the user and links properly. But to do the same operation with a custom action (invite), I can't find the way. Any ideas on solution? Thanks very much for the input!

Comment: Users that aren't saved to the database between requests are lost forever.  As such, there is no purpose to a `User.new` without a `save` in the request that produces the form.  Instead what you likely want to do is to have the invite request be a `collection` rather than a `member` operation, and have the `invite` operation do a `User.new`.  At most what you will want to do is pre-fill some (possibly hidden) fields when you generate the form using the values from the `params[:user]` hash.

Comment: Hmm, well i'm still new to ruby - do you know a good place to read up on collection vs member operations?

Comment: hmm i don't think it's a problem with collection vs member operations. I was wondering whether it has to do with the way the "invited" variable is initialized? typically saying @invited or invited=User.new makes the form submit to the 'create' action on the User controller. But I would want it to initialize and submit to the 'invite' action..

Comment: The Rails Guides on Routing (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) are pretty good.  Applying them to the matter at hand: Users is a collection, and an individual user in the database is a member of that collection.  Invite is an action.  Do you expect the urls to be something like http://localhost:3000/users/invite (i.e., a collection operation) or something like http://localhost:3000/users/5/invite (i.e., a member operation)?  If the former, change your routing to say `collection` instead of `member`.  If the latter, save the new User after you create it.

Comment: hey - good news, your solution (switching to collection) does work. Once switched to a collection, then the form for syntax is form_for(invited, :url => invite_users_path). It didn't work before because i wrote invite_user_path not invite_users_path. If you want to add an answer to this question, i'll happily check it as correct and give you some points.