# Custom Functions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm a rails beginner and I'm trying to get the concept down in my head. Even though we have  functions like "index, show" I was wondering the custom functions, like whether we can create them

I'm developing the back end of a mobile application and I have to present the response of the login request. I would like to enable the URL 'http://www.mysite.com/**client**/login' where **client** being my model. Would it be possible for me to define a function like **login** in my **client controller.**

Comment: Those are better referred to as actions, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364858/ruby-on-rails-custom-actions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! You start by defining your new action in your controller.

in app/controllers/clients_controller.rb

```
class ClientsController < Application Controller
  def index
    ...
  end

  def show
    ...
  end

  def login
    ...
  end
end
```

And then in config/routes.rb

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :clients do
    member do
      get 'login'
    end
  end
end
```

You have to modify the routes.rb file because your application doesn't know how to handle custom controller actions by default!

Depending on what you want to do once you've processed the login, you can put a redirect in your #login respond_to block or add a login.html.erb in your app/clients/views directory.